# Start axis at zero with axis()

Tags: r, plot, axis-labels

This must be a really simple cause, but I did not find the answer. I want to add an y-axis to a plot with `axis()`with the starting point at zero.
Usually I would solve the problem with `ylim()` but in `axis()` the parameter doesn't exist.

Here is my code, I need to root-transform the y-axis

```
 y <- seq(0,1500,300)
 plot(y, yaxt = "n")
 axis(2, sqrt(seq(0,1500,300)), labels = seq(0,1500,300), las = 1)
```

This code draws an axis at the right position with the right labels, except for the missing zero and the missing tickmark at zero.

Is there a parameter to define the limits of the axis in `axis()`?

Comment: Can you add a full example please to make this reproducible as your code seems to do what you want ex/ `plot(1,type="n", ylim=c(0,sqrt(1500)), axes=FALSE) ;
 axis(2, at=sqrt(seq(0,1500,300)), labels = seq(0,1500,300), las = 1)`

Comment: That was quite simple, thanks a lot!!